# .htaccess problem adding www to the url and removing index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure why my code doesn't work.
I want to add www to the url and when they enter **http://domain.co.uk/index.php**
it will become **http://www.domain.co.uk/** only
here is my htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule index\.php http://www.domain.co.uk/ [NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Does it redirect you to the wrong place? Some other error? Be more specific.

Comment: the url is not changing. that is what happens

Comment: I just figure out, it is a zeus server. this is the first time I heard about zeus rewrite script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Few minor corrections in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [NC,R,L]
```

- `.` needs to be escaped in conditions otherwise it will match any character
- Mark each individual rule as last by placing `L`
- Enclose conditions in `^` and `$` to mark begin and end of match

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still need an answer to this. Use another .htaccess. Get guide from here, I found it and it looks good: http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Remember, once you have your CodeIgniter htaccess file setup, you will want to go into your “/system/application/config/config.php”, find the following:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

and change it to:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```